# exe file downloaded from cloud not running from cmd

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to download and run a file from dropbox OR Google drive via powershell/cmd. The file works fine when I manually run it before and after upload to the cloud. However, whenever I try to run it via cmd it get the windows alert error saying "This version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program." Why is it only failing when I run via cmd?

sys.network.exe is the name of the file. C:\appDir\ is the directory to download and run the file.

In powershell:

```
$url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=11NiMkKDZC0eLs9YoXBnHxzpdAU4aj9ua"
$output = "C:\appDir\sys.network.exe"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

Then in cmd, I navigate to the output folder and run:
    sys.network.exe

Comment: Why did you ask two duplicate questions? I am voting to flag this question as duplicate.

Comment: Try running it using the  64-bit cmd.exe